# Weighted sum of pytrees in JAX

Tags: python, jax

I have a pytree represented by a list of lists holding parameter tuples. The sub-lists all have the same structure (see example).

Now I would like to create a weighted sum so that the resulting pytree has the same structure as one of the sub-lists. The weights for each sub-list are stored in a separate array / list.

So far I have the following code that seems to works but requires several steps and for-loop that I would like avoid for performance reasons.

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

list_1 = [
    [jnp.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), jnp.asarray([2, 3])],
    [jnp.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), jnp.asarray([2, 3])],
]

list_2 = [
    [jnp.asarray([[2, 3], [3, 4]]), jnp.asarray([5, 3])],
    [jnp.asarray([[2, 3], [3, 4]]), jnp.asarray([5, 3])],
]

list_3 = [
    [jnp.asarray([[7, 1], [4, 4]]), jnp.asarray([6, 2])],
    [jnp.asarray([[6, 4], [3, 7]]), jnp.asarray([7, 3])],
]

weights = [1, 2, 3] 
pytree = [list_1, list_2, list_3]

weighted_pytree = [jax.tree_map(lambda tree: weight * tree, tree) for weight, tree in zip(weights, pytree)]
reduced = jax.tree_util.tree_map(lambda *args: sum(args), *weighted_pytree)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you have in mind:

```py
def wsum(*args, weights=weights):
  return jnp.asarray(weights) @ jnp.asarray(args)

reduced = jax.tree_util.tree_map(wsum, *pytree)
```

For the edited question, where tree elements have more general shapes, you can define `wsum` like this instead:

```py
def wsum(*args, weights=weights):
  return sum(weight * arg for weight, arg in zip(weights, args))
```

Comment: I tried your example which works but only for a specific tree structure. I made the pytree's structure a bit more complex and now I get the error `dot_general requires contracting dimensions to have the same shape.` I updated the question to cover that error.

Comment: OK, see edits to the answer above.

Comment: Great! Why is in these cases Python's `sum`  used and not `jax.numpy.sum`? And is there a way to pass parameters like floats to `wsum` using `tree_map` or do I have to get used to closures when working with JAX?

Comment: Because `jax.numpy.sum` only works on arrays, and what you have is a list/generator expression of arrays. You could call `jax.numpy.sum(jnp.stack(list(args)), axis=0)` if you wanted to go that route, but that would involve extra memory allocation.